# How to parse a specific xml file using PHP simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I know there is already a lot of topics about simpleXML and PHP, but I need help with an specific xml code.

```
<vitrine>
  <canal>Hotwords</canal>

  <product id="0">
    <descricao>MP3 Apple iPod Class...</descricao>
    <loja>ApetreXo.com</loja>

    <preco>&#224; vista R$765,22</preco>
    <urlImagem>http://imagem.domain.com.br/thumbs/ensopado/18/80x80_107156_1.jpg</urlImagem>
    <urlProduto>http://domain.com.br/tr/rd?o=BiY4C2UnHQ0LOWgyGjc3NRFp-</urlProduto>
  </product>

  <product id="1">
    <descricao>TV Sony Bravia 3D LE...</descricao>

    <loja>Fast Shop.com.b...</loja>
    <preco>10 x R$299,90</preco>
    <urlImagem>http://imagem.domain.com.br/thumbs/ensopado/2852/80x80_319373_1.jpg</urlImagem>
    <urlProduto>http://domain.com.br/tr/rd?o=JDEn-</urlProduto>
  </product>

</vitrine>
```

I need a foreach to get the data from each "product" like this:

```
<?
$feedUrl = 'url to xml file';
$rawFeed = file_get_contents($feedUrl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rawFeed);

foreach ($item ...????? ?)
{    

}
```

How can I do this foreach to get the data. I tried all that I know without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` as the first line in your XML, otherwise it's not valid.  Then, and this will help you debug all sorts of things over your coding career, try this line:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($xml,true)."</pre>";
```

That will give you the exact layout of the object you get back from the `simplexml_load_string()` call.  From there, since you have a visual of the object layout, you should be able to figure out how to parse it.  Incidentally, in your case, I think you'd need to do something like:

```
foreach($xml->vitrine as $element) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems PHP gets rid of evrything after the whitespace, because `product id` was changed to just `product`. Anyway here's the code.

```
<?php
$v = <<<ABC
<vitrine>
  <canal>Hotwords</canal>

  <product id="0">
    <descricao>MP3 Apple iPod Class...</descricao>
    <loja>ApetreXo.com</loja>

    <preco>&#224; vista R$765,22</preco>
    <urlImagem>http://imagem.domain.com.br/thumbs/ensopado/18/80x80_107156_1.jpg</urlImagem>
    <urlProduto>http://domain.com.br/tr/rd?o=BiY4C2UnHQ0LOWgyGjc3NRFp-</urlProduto>
  </product>

  <product id="1">
    <descricao>TV Sony Bravia 3D LE...</descricao>

    <loja>Fast Shop.com.b...</loja>
    <preco>10 x R$299,90</preco>
    <urlImagem>http://imagem.domain.com.br/thumbs/ensopado/2852/80x80_319373_1.jpg</urlImagem>
    <urlProduto>http://domain.com.br/tr/rd?o=JDEn-</urlProduto>
  </product>

</vitrine>
ABC;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($v);
//print_r($xml);

foreach ($xml->product as $c){    
    echo $c->loja; //echoing out value of 'loja'
}
```

Outputs

```
ApetreXo.com
Fast Shop.com.b...
```